# Fargate, retrieve container from ECR with public IP off

Tags: aws-fargate

Could review my case?
While running a task that initiates Fargate containers I receive the following error:

ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ECR registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by

#### Configuration

- auto-assign a public IP to the task's elastic network interface (ENI) is off.
- The attached subnets have routes to the internet gateway. `0.0.0.0/0    igw-06fe0dabd17281f51`
- Security group allows outbound traffic anywhere. `sgr-044001697d4c97b32 IPv4    All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0`
- Network ACL allows everything `outbound 00  All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   Allow`

#### My opinion

It is not AMI role because. It works with auto-assigned IP.
This is the main starting point. It loads containers from ECR with auto-assigned IP.
It can not with disabled public IP
I saw an example where a guy created a NAT gateway with public IP. It is more secure because it can be defended by the security group.
I do not want the public IP because the containers become insecure.
But I do not understand why the internet gateway with routing for the subnet without public IP does not work for this case. Does ECS require a
direct connection to Fargate?
Can PrivateLink help me?

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Gateway just gives the resources in the subnet a link to the Internet, but those resources **have to have a public IP** in order to use the Internet Gateway. The Internet Gateway does not proxy the traffic and provide its own public IP. If you want something that proxies all the traffic to the Internet and provides its own public IP then you would have to add a NAT Gateway to your VPC and route the traffic through that.

Alternatively, if your tasks just need to access ECR, you could look into adding a [VPC Endpoint for ECR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) to your VPC.

Comment: I do not understand the need for public IP here. It is not required for connection from a container to a server. The public IP is required when somebody tries to connect from the outside world. That is why I am asking. Endpoints look like a solution.

Comment: The server is trying to connect to something outside the VPC. ECR exists outside the VPC. ECR is not a server running inside your virtual network, it is running outside of that. If your server (ECS) only has a private IP then it will be unable to connect to anything outside of the VPC. The private IP ONLY works within the VPC.

Comment: A public IP is not **just** needed for someone connecting from the outside world, it is **also** needed when your server tries to connect to something that exists in the outside world. ECR exists outside the world of your private network (VPC).